# Edit triggers for a Windows Task Scheduler Task

Tags: powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

We currently have several hundred tasks scheduled in Windows Task Scheduler on our server 2008 box. There are a number of tasks that are running every half hour indefinitely. Is there any way to use a script to change the triggers on those tasks so that they will only run every half hour M-F?

Comment: How are the tasks named? Did you follow a naming convention?

Comment: We do! ProjectName - Job_Name_foo

Comment: That is positive, I'm trying to work a solution where we can use VBS to recursively work through the XML's and change the ScheduleByDaily to ScheduleByWeek and then adding the empty child nodes for MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI... the only issue is that I'm not particularly familiar with VBS

Comment: Haha I hear that =] it shouldn't be that hard to implement something that goes through these. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use the [TaskService COM object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-objects). For some example scripts that use this object, see the following:

1. [Rename Scheduled Tasks in Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Vista](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-script-rename-scheduled-tasks-windows-7-windows-server-2008-and-windows-vista)
2. [How-To: Use PowerShell to Report on Scheduled Tasks](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/how-use-powershell-report-scheduled-tasks)
3. [Updating a Scheduled Task's Credentials](https://www.itprotoday.com/devops-and-software-development/updating-scheduled-tasks-credentials)

   Script: https://gist.github.com/Bill-Stewart/363fdf761499a071439c8ac0c18dcd54

Using the schtasks.exe utility is rather limited past Windows XP/Server 2003.

Comment: I think you need to update to PS v3 for this.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Comment: The scripts I wrote (see links above) require only version 2; version 3 is not required.

Comment: Bill, this is what I ended up going with, so thanks a lot for the direction on this

Comment: Glad you guys got it figured out!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the allowed options for /SC:

```
/SC allows for the following frequency schedules:
        MINUTE:     1 - 1439 minutes.
        HOURLY:     1 - 23 hours.
        DAILY:      1 - 365 days.
        WEEKLY:     weeks 1 - 52. (/D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN)
        ONCE:       No modifiers.
        ONSTART:    No modifiers.
        ONLOGON:    No modifiers.
        ONIDLE:     No modifiers.
        MONTHLY:    1 - 12, or FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH, LAST, LASTDAY.**
```

*I keep editing this because I'm not happy with my findings...*

I have looked into the SCHTASKS and noticed that you cannot CHANGE for the schedule through CMD.

**From [technet.microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx)**

Changes one or more of the following properties of a task.

- The program that the task runs (/tr).
- The user account under which the task runs (/ru).
- The password for the user account (/rp).

I am going to continue to do some research on this, and hopefully will edit this answer with a workable solution.

**EDIT**
If you look in C:\windows\system32\tasks you will find all of your scheduled tasks
They're not listed as XML, but they are indeed XML
What I think should be done is using either; VBS or C# application dig to each of the following Nodes 
//Task/Triggers/CalendarTrigger to delete /ScheduleByDay and it's child node /DaysInterval
//Task/Triggers/CalendarTrigger to create the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
   -<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task" version="1.2"> 
     +<RegistrationInfo> 
     -<Triggers> 
       -<CalendarTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2013-03-13T15:20:00</StartBoundary>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled> 
             -<ScheduleByWeek> 
               -<DaysOfWeek> 
                    <Monday/>
                    <Tuesday/> 
                    <Wednesday/> 
                    <Thursday/> 
                    <Friday/> 
                </DaysOfWeek>
                <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval> 
              </ScheduleByWeek> 
       </CalendarTrigger> 
     </Triggers>
```

If anyone can pick up and run with this - I don't think I'll be able to do much with this in the next week.

Comment: IIRC, the schtasks.exe command is very limited with the new Task Scheduler APIs. This is why I suggested accessing the scheduler directly using the COM object.

Comment: @AbqBill Ya, I see that... stinks :(

Comment: dunno why I keep getting upvoted for this, I haven't necessarily provided any solution :P
I'm still looking though...

Comment: It's getting upvoted by people that haven't actually tried it. :)

Comment: I did some looking, and Windows (unfortunately for me) makes hashes of these task files, stores them in the registry, and compares the hash to the files so you can't really edit them. Darn you Microsoft, making things secure!

Comment: Hmm, interesting - I'll keep looking, this week i'm busy, but next week when I'm around I'll start digging some more. Not a problem, I love a good challenge!

Comment: Just use the TaskService COM object, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: For those who messed up by changing the task xml directly. here is the fix. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2305420

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you use SCHTASKS /Create and use the same /TN name with a different /SC and /ST options it will overwrite the existing scheduled task with the updated schedule